# CNN for ordinal classification

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, image-classification, class-imbalance, convolutional-neural-network

How do we design a CNN for ordinal classification?

I am trying to analyze plant leaf images for diseases. I've got the disease type classification working. Now we need to classify the magnitude of the disease affliction on a scale of 1 to 10 (ordinal scale), where 1 is almost no trace of diseased parts on the leaf and 10 is completely diseased.

1. Is it possible to construct a CNN for this task?
2. How do I deal with the imbalance in training samples for each ordinal level?

Comment: [This](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.05278.pdf) paper may be of interest; it shows that you can improve ordinal classification metrics by constraining the output distribution to be unimodal

Answer (score 1):

NN aren't ideal for regression tasks.

I'd train 10 networks, one for each magnitude.

CNN #k would be a binary classifier predicting whether the magnitude is **k or less**

In other words, CNN #10 is a function that always returns 1, and CNN#0 is the binary classifier you've already trained.

Comment: Why do you think NNs aren’t ideal for regression tasks? Do you have a source?

Answer (score 1):

Use the same model you trained for the classification task, and append it with 10 logistic units which indicates respectively whether if the magnitude is k or less, as previously suggested.

As for the imbalance problem, you could pick your batch examples to have equal probability for all the classes.

**An intuitive explanation:**

Class A contains 10 examples while class B contains 90 examples.
duplicate each example of the class A eight times, and then shuffle both classes examples, then during training, keep sampling from a uniform distribution.

Of course, you don't need to duplicate the example data explicitly, just keep a list of indices mapped to your input vectors and start duplicating from there.